# Is it possible to make review optional on any particular branch in gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

With my information, non-admins may not create a new branch. However, is he/she creates one (or gets it created by taking help of someone admin), he/she would still need to get every commit reviewed before merging into branch. Can we avoid this kind of a scenario where pushing something into a less important branch need not go through review process (without making someone an admin)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should create a subset of branches/references and give permission where everybody can create such branch and can push commit directly.
So create a new reference like `refs/heads/feature-[a-zA-Z]*` and add *Create Reference*, *Push* - with Force Push option to able to delete branches, *Push Merge Commit*
you can find more info about [Access controls](https://review.typo3.org/Documentation/access-control.html) there.

Comment: Nit: For `refs/heads/feature-[a-zA-Z]*` to be recognized as a regexp in the Gerrit config the pattern must be prepended by `^`.